# Node.JS to OSC via UDP

Tags: node.js, udp, osc

I installed [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) and integrated [Socket.io](http://socket.io/).

In a file called "appudp.js", I have the following code:

```
var dgram = require('dgram');

var message = new Buffer("5656"); // Whatever the number could be...

var client = dgram.createSocket("udp4");

client.on("error", function (err) {

console.log("Socket error: " + err);

});

// At every second, send a message...

setInterval(function(){

client.send(message, 0, message.length, 1337, "127.0.0.1", function(err, bytes) {

  console.log("err : " + err + " | bytes : " + bytes + " | Message : " + message);

});

}, 1000);
```

I go in command prompt, type "node app.js". I get at every 1000 ms:

> err: null | bytes: 4 | Message: 5656

All good so far.

In MaxMsp, I have this very simple patch:

[image]

Yet, as you can see in the screen capture, it gives me the error :

> OSC Bad message name string: DataAfterAlignedString: Unreasonably long string Dropping entire message.

Being somewhat new to MaxMsp, I end up being completely lost. Help?

Comment: spotting this on the cycling74 forums http://bb-attachments.cycling74.com.s3.amazonaws.com/2455.HowtoOSCUDPMaxMSP.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not sending OSC, but arbitrary UDP packets. Note that the udpreceive object expects OSC-formatted packets, as generalhenry suggests.

To format messages as OSC, you could use a library like https://github.com/termie/node-osc.